# How can I use foreach and hide other result if it has the same date?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a to get the `slots` of each product with the same `date` and same `product_id` and hide other data if the date is already been shown the first time
I use this code below in my controller to add all the slots with the same date

```
public function show($id) {
    $product = Products::findOrFail($id);
    $bookings = Bookings::get();
    $slots = Bookings::groupBy(['date', 'product_id'])->selectRaw('sum(slots) as total, date, product_id')->get();

    return view('service', compact('product', 'bookings', 'slots'));
}
```

And here below I used this to filter out each product

```
@foreach ($bookings as $booking)
  @if ($booking->product_id == $product->id)
    @foreach ($slots as $slot)
      @if ($booking->date == $slot->date && $booking->product_id == $slot->product_id)
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{$slot}}
      </li>
      @endif
    @endforeach
  @endif
@endforeach
```

but the result is always showing all the date with the same date and the same slots because it already added up

Answer (score 0):

You can use one array, and push to that array date that already displayed, and before showing check is that date exist in array, if no show it, else not show

```
    @foreach ($bookings as $booking)
  @if ($booking->product_id == $product->id)
    $dates = [];
    @foreach ($slots as $slot)
      @if ($booking->date == $slot->date && $booking->product_id == $slot->product_id)
      @if(!isset($dates[$slot->date]))
      <?php $dates[$slot->date] = true;
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{$slot}}
      </li>
       @endif
      @endif
    @endforeach
  @endif
@endforeach
```

it Should be better implement this logic in controller, I only suggest you solution, for example.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I don't know why but it's still showing the same results as before after I followed your answer